# Arduino-Processing Serial.send/Serial.get interaction

Tags: java, serialization, arduino, processing

I'm trying to get my Arduino environment to send data to processing for a data visualization project.

I have managed to get the handshake working and can Serial.println(...) to print the data I need from Arduino to the Processing console. What I need now is to somehow use that data to alter a variable within Processing.

I know that neither of the methods that I mention in the title exist within the Serial class but I was hoping someone would know how to manage this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the relevant Processing code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using the `serialEvent` method in processing. Example code:

```
String val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Where myPort is the port that your android device is on.

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't realized that the Serial.println(...) was printing to a string value, _then_ being printed in Processing! Thanks so much, Dan!